# CPU1 80-90% After Installing Ubunto on Microsoft Surface Book 2

Tags: cpu, surface

I'm a new linux user. Searching for solutions I found this is a kworker problem, however I couldn't find a solution that I understood and could implement well or actually worked. I spent all morning trying to utilize the solutions posted here and also tried jakedays kernel installation available on github found here:

https://github.com/jakeday/linux-surface

I carefully followed his directions and after running neofetch was still unable to see a different version of kernel mine is fixed on kernel version 5.3.0-46-generic:

[neofetch-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXYwl.png)

The jakeday github was trying to have me install 5.1.15-1. However again, after I finished installing the github files and following his directions there was no change. My CPU continued to look like this:
[CPU-History](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofmBB.png)

I found a lot of the solutions extremely hard to follow due to my newness to this. If anyone knows a solution I would be extremely thankful if they could help me get through this. Thank you.

EDIT: I installed Ubuntu 19.10 via USB (using this link https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop )  and then installed KDE-full by terminal using this website: https://itsfoss.com/install-kde-on-ubuntu/

EDIT2: I believe this is a problem because when I searched online, it was viewed as a problem for other users. They deemed it a problem with the kworker and were offered solutions that worked. Futhermore it is listed as a common bug. However, since I'm new to Linux and programming I was unable to understand how to implement the solutions I found.

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: Your image seems to show one of your eight cores is running at 80%, the others are barely ticking at all. That looks like a laptop conserving power to me...normal behavior. What leads you to believe that there is a problem? And what leads you to believe that kworker (which is a normal kernel thread) is involved with the problem?

Comment: I have added an edit in response to both of you.